# Regex code to allow everything **but** line breaks

Tags: regex

Im trying so hard to understand this RegEx coding but i'm not quite that good at it.  I need a Regex code to allow everything **but** line breaks and I can't figure it out.  Anything I put in prompts errors in my form.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have code you are using? What language? `\v` should be a vertical space. If you are talking about HTML line breaks it would be `<br\h?/?>`..

Comment: What do you mean, "allow everything but line breaks"? What do you want to achieve? Test whether a text does not contain line breaks? Split a text by line breaks? For both, there may be better approaches than regex, depending on your language.

Answer (score -1):

Use a negated character class of "line feed" characters:

```
^[^\r\n]*$
```

Although a "line feed" is just `\n`, the "carriage return" character `\r` is usually included too. If that's a problem, then use just `^[^\n]*$`.

Comment: `^.*$` can be used as well if the mode that makes the dot match everything is turned off (provided such a mode exists in the to-be-used flavor).